# Clone Table Output and Display In Popup With Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This might be fairly simple. I have a table that I generate dynamically with php/mysql lets just say for example;

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to copy the entire html of this table, so that I can display it on another page in php. How would I go about doing this? Could I store the html in a php session somehow?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If the table is generated in php and you want to use it later, again in php, then yes you can store it in the session (or in a connected database) so it can be retrieved later. More typically, you would save the data from which the table was built, and rebuild it when needed - this would generally be more economical of storage. There's no need to involve javascript/jQuery unless some user interaction is needed to allow/disallow storage of the table and even then it should not be necessary to send the table itself back to the server from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

To answer your question directly, you can get the contents of your table using [jQuery's html method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with:

`var myTabelContents = $('#mytable').html();`

Then inject it into another html element, we'll say *mytable2*, with:

`$('#mytable2').html(myTableContents);`.

This would require the popup to be generated in page, without the user actually leaving the page you're on.  *(Leaving the page would destroy the object stored in javascript memory).*

There are ways to save this data locally, so that it can be viewed on subsequent pages by taking advantage of HTML5, or by saving the information to a cookie or PHP session.

However, based on what you have described, this sounds to me like a solution best handled in PHP with *include* or *require*.  In PHP, you can include the contents of any file into any other file.  I would consider saving your table to an external file, such as *mytable.template.php*.  You can than include that table on any number of pages, with an include statement.  For example:

**in page1.php..**

`include 'mytable.template.php';`

Be sure to read up on the difference between *include* and *require*, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax is the way more easy to send data o any type to other pages or files

```
<input type='text' id='myfield' />
$.ajax({
    url: 'myOtherFile.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'myvar='+ $('#myfield').val(),
    success: function(answerData){
         $('#whereIlikeputMydata').html(answerData);
    }
});
```

So all your data and connect function are in other file like this

```
$data=$_POST['myvar'];
 #do all operations with your var $data and print it
echo $myResult;
```